# Selinux 'var_t' base type warning

Tags: nginx, centos, httpd, selinux, uwsgi

I am currently 'lost' in the CentOS Selinux forest.

My setup involves setting up a WSGI socket in `/var/www/demo/out` which nginx uses to communicate with the UWSGI process. Whenever I request the page in my browser I get an nginx error.

**Why is this Selinux related?**

- Disabling Selinux with `setenforce 0` fixes it.
- /var/log/audit/audit.log and audit2why display a `denied` and `missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule`

I have tried adding the `httpd_sys_content_t` label to the socket so nginx was allowed to read and write to the socket file, restorecon after adding the new label.

Running the violation through `audit2allow` returns the following policy:

```
module nginx 1.0;

require {
        type httpd_t;
        type var_t;
        type httpd_sys_content_t;
        class sock_file write;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t httpd_sys_content_t:sock_file write;

#!!!! WARNING: 'var_t' is a base type.
allow httpd_t var_t:sock_file write;
```

The first rule I understand, however what is the second rule conveying? I am guessing because the nginx process is requesting a tcontext that has `var_t` in it a new selinux policy is required that includes this new context?

So why is this warning here? Is it complaining that adding a directory like var to a policy is too general / isn't specific enough? If this is the case, can't this policy be narrowed to something like `var_www_t`? Also if this is the case then why is the uwsgi process, which is running under a non root user, allowed to write to the socket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider placing your socket in a location where SELinux already expects it to be.

```
# semanage fcontext -l | grep httpd_var_run_t | grep wsgi
/var/run/wsgi.*                                    socket             system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
```

Thus if you create `/run/wsgi.anything` and use that as the socket then it will work perfectly. Keep in mind that since this is a temporary directory cleared on every boot, you should create the socket yourself at startup, usually with [a `tmpfiles.d` configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html). For example:

```
p+ /run/wsgi.anything 0660 user group - -
```

Comment: Do you maybe have a link / ref / tooling to the different selinux policies being explained? I have no idea what the exact definition of `httpd_var_run_t` is.

Comment: In my opinion the cleanest answer. Requires no custom Selinux policies to be created.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good reference for each of them. This is unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is there because you may be giving too much away. You allowing httpd to write to any socket in /var which may not be what you want.

The httpd_sys_content_t context only allows read access to a file unless you have enabled the httpd_unified boolean. If you want your socket to be writable by httpd you need to set it to be httpd_sys_rw_content_t

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/demo/out"
restorecon -Rv /var/www/demo/out
```

<sup><sup><sup><sup>Michael Hampton will be along soon to correct me I'm sure</sup></sup></sup></sup>

Comment: +1 for the fine print ;)

Answer (score 1):

A selinux base type is a generic type which, when granted, allow access to a very significant portion of the underlying system. Enabling selinux access for `var_t` is almost equiparable to run the process unconfined.

From [the blog of one of the selinux developer:](https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/69958.html)

> The thing we really want to stop is domains writing to BASE types.  If
>   I allow a confined domain to write to a BASE type like etc_t or usr_t,
>   then a hacked system can attack other domains, since almost all other
>   domains need to read some etc_t or usr_t content.

Files under `/var/www/` are already labeled with `httpd_sys_content_t`; by relabeling it with the same label you change nothing. From what I remember, `httpd_sys_content_t` should be used for static HTML files rather than sockets.  Try relabeling your socket with something as:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_var_run_t </your/socket/path>
restorecon -RF </your/socket/path>
```

You can read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/763472/how-can-i-tell-selinux-to-permit-nginx-access-to-a-unix-socket-without-audit2all) for a similar problem.